# Viewing plaintext files in light mode in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, darkmode

I want to view a plaintext file in light color theme in Firefox. Firefox is showing the file in dark mode by default (I am using Firefox dark mode, and I don't want to change that). I could see the css code setting the theme, but could not edit it permanently (it changed back when I reopened the text file). Is there a solution to this?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use something like this in a user-stylesheet:

```
@-moz-document plain-text-document() {
  :root {
    background-color: initial !important;
    color: initial !important;
  }
}
```

Though we could add a pref for that if you file a bug for it :)

Comment: Perfect! For any future viewer I would mention that you can change style sheet following these steps, for example: https://superuser.com/questions/318912/how-can-i-override-the-css-of-a-site-in-firefox-with-usercontent-css

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to file a bug!

Comment: bugzilla.mozilla.org :-)